# Can I set some bones to move Like hair?

Tags: scripting, bones, constraints

I want some bones to move like hair that collides with itself, but I can't figure out how. How can I do this to my model?[image: My model with bones]

Comment: Look into creating a ragdoll rig. The technique sets up an armature that moves using rigid body physics.

Comment: Its not working that much for my model

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing with a rope rig of my own.
This is possible by applying the required physics to separate objects each approximating the chunks of "hair" in the areas of each bone. Then constrain the bones to the objects.
To save time I've included a link to the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sf_THDaxNSo). It goes through the same issues with a hat. The benefit is this not only moves like hair but if used right can have active collisions.